# Performance drop when writing NSCoding objects to disk

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on an iOS game that generates chunks of 2d tiles the user can move around "infinitely".

Just for context: Each tile is 32x32px and each "chunk" contains 4x4 tiles (16 total). Most tiles are empty, but when something gets placed on a tile, and if the user moves too far away and that chunk "unloads" - I save the chunk and tile data to disk.

Right now, the chunk and tile are each using the `NSCoding` protocol. The chunk saves the `NSArray` of tiles and a few booleans, and each tile saves couple numbers/booleans.

This works perfectly - when the chunk unloads it saves, when the chunk is loaded again, it's restored.

However, I'm noticing that the write to disk method kills my FPS extremely briefly. Since there are usually several chunks unloaded together as the player moves, and by the time they're unloaded the player has moved further and more and unloading - it adds up.

I've already done all I can to ensure only chunks with actually changes are saved, and I've better organized the save code to avoid instantiating objects every save call.

Is there a better way I can save data without impacting FPS?

- Since I'm usually saving data that's not visible on-screen, can I do this async?
- Is there a faster method than NSCoding, since it's just some float/bool values per class?

Here's the Chunk save code:

```
-(void)saveToDisk {
    if( !self.hasUnsavedChanges ){
        NSLog(@"skipping saving chunk that has not changed");
        return;
    }
    [self.saveFile writeData:self withKey:self.savefileKey];
    self.hasUnsavedChanges = false;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.position.x] forKey:@"chunk.x"];
    [encoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.position.y] forKey:@"chunk.y"];
    [encoder encodeObject:tiles forKey:@"chunk.tiles"];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {

    Chunk *restore = [self init];

    NSNumber *xChunkNum = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"chunk.x"];
    NSNumber *yChunkNum = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"chunk.y"];
    restore.position = [Coord coordWithX:[xChunkNum intValue] Y:[yChunkNum intValue]];

    tiles = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"chunk.tiles"];

    return restore;
}
```

And the tile code:

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.worldContextCoordinate.x] forKey:@"tile.world.x"];
    [encoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.worldContextCoordinate.y] forKey:@"tile.world.y"];
    [encoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.color.red] forKey:@"tile.color.red"];
    [encoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.color.green] forKey:@"tile.color.green"];
    [encoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.color.blue] forKey:@"tile.color.blue"];
    [encoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.isSourceTile] forKey:@"tile.isSource"];forKey:@"tile.hasBlackNeighbor"];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {

    Tile *restore = [self init];

    NSNumber *xNum = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"tile.world.x"];
    NSNumber *yNum = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"tile.world.y"];
    [restore setWorldContextCoordinate:b2Vec2( [xNum floatValue], [yNum floatValue] )];

    NSNumber *red = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"tile.color.red"];
    NSNumber *green = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"tile.color.green"];
    NSNumber *blue = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"tile.color.blue"];

    restore.color = [CCColor colorWithRed:[red floatValue] green:[green floatValue] blue:[blue floatValue]];

    restore.isSourceTile = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"tile.isSource"];

    return restore;
}
```

Comment: Are you dependent on the completion of saving these? As in, could there be an event happened that required them to be saved to disk before it could begin? If so, then async is probably going to be a nightmare even with completion blocks. Other than CoreData, you're probably on the right track with NSCoding.

Comment: Not really. These are generally saved when I "unload" them - when the user has moved away and this "land" is no longer needed. All that needs the end result is when the data is loaded again, when the user comes back to this spot and the chunk data is loaded.

Comment: Use the profiler and/or time logging to determine where the time is. Then you can decide what to speed up. You will know the time spent in NSCoding vs the disk write time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the fact that you don't need to worry about completion events affecting UI or UX, you should be able to run these asynchronously. You could do this with a completion block if need be too, so that you can handle the completion events if necessary.

```
- (void)saveToDiskAsyncWithCompletion:(void(^)(BOOL finished))completion
{    
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, NO), ^{
        [self saveToDisk];
        // or you could run any of your other operations here too.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            completion(YES);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you think there's any possible way of getting away with loading the data async, as well? Looking at new profiling data and the initWithCoder for my Tile object is still a decent chunk of time, still impacting fps.

Comment: There is - you'll need to use the completion block like that in your method so that you can notify the system when it's complete. When you call the method, put your UI updates inside the completion block.